# JavaScript Form Validation using function and if statement

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events

Look at this code:

```
var UserName = document.getElementById("username");
var PassWord = document.getElementById("password");

function ValidateFormBeforePHP() {

    if (UserName.value == "" || UserName.value.length < 10) { alert("Please fill in username or characters to 10 or more"); }
    UserName.focus();
    UserName.style.border = "1px solid red");

    if (PassWord.value == "" || PassWord.value.length < 10) { alert("Please fill in password or characters to 10 or more"); }
    PassWord.focus();
    PassWord.style.border = "1px solid red");

    return false;

}
```

If both statement are false it does not post / Login.

Comment: So what is suppose to return the function to work? What is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be somewhat like this:

```
function ValidateFormBeforePHP() {

    if (UserName.value == "" || UserName.value.length < 10) {
        alert("Please fill in username or characters to 10 or more");
        UserName.focus();
        UserName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
    }


    if (PassWord.value == "" || PassWord.value.length < 10) {
        alert("Please fill in password or characters to 10 or more");
        PassWord.focus();
        PassWord.style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```